# Hover effect on background image

Tags: css, wordpress, html, hover

I've added a black transparency to appear when they hover on a background image on my site. I have a h2 tag which also appears on the hover but sits behind the dark transparency where as I want it on top of it! Is there a solution to this?

```
<div class="img-option"> 
    <div class="content"> 
        <h2>example<\h2> 
    <\div>
<\div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-option 
Background image Position relative Background repeat no repeat Background Size cover .img-option:hover Filter: brightness (.6)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add your relevant HTML and CSS, you can use jsfiddle.net or similar to show the problem.

Comment: <div class="img-option"> <div class="content"> <h2>example<\h2> <\div><\div>  CSS: .img-option Background image Position relative  Background repeat no repeat Background Size cover  .img-option:hover Filter: brightness (.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.img-option {
  background-image: url(https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/106/719/original/vector-abstract-blue-wave-background.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.img-option:after,
h2:before {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
}

.img-option:after {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h2:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  top: 60%;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  border: solid #000000 1px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.img-option:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-option">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 data-content="example"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All works fine thank you! apart from the transparency on hover makes the white h2 and off grey so it's still applying the transparency over it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to assign a z-index to your `<h2>` element.

```
z-index: 1;
```

You can find out more about the the z-index property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Answer (score 0):

add `.img-option:before` element and add style `position:absolute` and adjust the height like below.

**DEMO:-**

```css
.img-option {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-option h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.img-option:before {
    content: '\00a0';
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
}

.img-option:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-option">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>example</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```